# Resize HTML5 Canvas Circle onclick

Tags: javascript, html, scale

Trying to double the size of a circle onclick(). Doesn't seem to be working?

HTML

`<canvas id="drawing" width="600px" height="600px" onclick="resize()"></canvas>`

Javascript

```
        window.onload = function() {
            canvas=document.getElementById("drawing");
            context=canvas.getContext("2d");
            var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
            var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
            var radius = 70;

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            context.fillStyle = 'green';
            context.fill();
        }

        function resize () {
            context.fillStyle= "#701be0"; // This changes the rectangle to blue
            context.fill();
            context.scale(10.5, 2.5); 
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redraw your circle again and also keep in mind that `context.scale()` will also  scale its position so i wouldn't recommend to do it this way. You can just draw a new circle over with bigger radius.

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/DSFMq/

Comment: The issue with redrawing it is that I also want to add a transition. Doesn't seem to work then. Thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean by transition? You can clear canvas and draw circle again for every frame.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified. This is the effect I want, but I need to do it on the canvas:

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/M362A/

Comment: yep, you just clear canvas every frame and redraw circle with new size and position. check this tutorial - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Basic_animations

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsFiddle for exactly what I needed, in case anyone needs help.

http://jsfiddle.net/elijahmurray/fHv82/1/

```
x=200;
y=200;    
size=100;
radius=30;

function animate() {
reqAnimFrame =  window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || //get framerate
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame
            ;
reqAnimFrame(animate);


if(radius <= 200) {
    radius +=3; 
} //increase size by 1 per frame

    draw();
}

function draw() {
var canvas  = document.getElementById("ex1");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = 'green';
  context.fill();
}
animate();
```